# alert all selected value in SELECT - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i get all the selected value in tag SELECT?

```
<select id="list" multiple=multiple>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">one </option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">two </option>
    <option value="3">three </option>
</select>
```

for example use foreach as php???

live: http://jsfiddle.net/FMF7c/1/

how can i show with alert in this example one and two? I would like use JQUERY

Comment: this is almost on the **example** of the [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FMF7c/5/
I've used simple JavaScript to loop through all the options in the select element, and add any of which are selected to an array.

Hah, looks like you didn't need my help after all.

Answer (score 4):

The [`val()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method will return an Array for a multiple `<select>`.

```
alert( $('#list').val() ); // to show both
```

```
$.each( $('#list').val(), function(i,v) { alert( v ); }); // to show individual
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FdMMK/

Comment: +1 Wow nice.. never knew that, I generally stayed away from val and used value. Thanks for the info.

Comment: yay +1 - didn't know that it mappes those automatically, when was that actually implemented ?

Comment: @jAndy: Good question. Far as I know, it's always been that way, at least as long as I've used jQuery (since 1.4).

Comment: @jAndy: First appearance I can find is in jQuery 1.2. [Here's a link](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.1.js) to the source for 1.2.1.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#list").find("option:selected").each(function() { alert($(this).val()); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjL9n/1/

Answer (score 3):

I guess just "alerting" those values is not really what you want. To `.map()` those values into an Array, we can use the below:

```
var values = $('#list option:selected').map(function(_, node) {
    return node.value; // or node.textContent || node.text
}).get();

alert( values );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FMF7c/4/